# Workflows stuck 'in progress' when moved to SharePoint farm environment

Tags: workflow, deployment

We have developed a number of custom approval workflows in Visual Studio 2008. They basically create task and work through a 2 stage approval process, once a task is completed, it generates new tasks for stage 2, then completes.

These have been tested and work well in a single server MOSS SharePoint environment.

We have now moved them to a test farm environment with 2 Web Front Ends, 1 SSP/Search Server, 1 SQL Server.

The workflows now get stuck in progress, after completing the first stage of the workflow, as if the workflow is not recognising that something has changed.

No errors, in our logging code, none in the SP logs.

Would appreciate anyones thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a very simple workflow which does the following:

1. write to history list
2. create task
3. ontaskcompleted > write to history list
4. finish

(you could even leave out step 2 and 3)

If this completes fine on your test environment then it's likely to be a code issue.

If this one hangs as well, it's likely to be an environment/config issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy the solution to both the front ends? I would log every step completion to workflow history.. so I can easily know, where the workflow is breaking...

Comment: yeah we have logged it all to history but it stops at a successful stage and then no errors reported. The solution was deployed via stsadm and the dlls are on both WFE's

Comment: are they both in same environment (32bit/64bit)?
do you have proper connectivity between the farms? any firewall is blocking it?